# does not recognize me getRef (position) is onBindViewHolder working with Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I try to show a detail of the list but getref () does not recognize me,I want to get the key to go to another activity, help please, I'm new.

this is a class is not an activity

[image]

[image: I use this code in an activity and it works very well]

Comment: Please replace the pictures of code with the actual code as text. Having the code as text makes it searchable, and makes it easier to use that code in an answer.

Comment: Are you tring to get a key from your firebase database ?!

Answer (score 1):

`getRef()` in firebase does not accept parameters, from the documentation:

```
public DatabaseReference getRef ()
```

> Used to obtain a reference to the source location for this snapshot.
>
> Returns:
>
> A DatabaseReference corresponding to the location that this snapshot came from

You can do this:

Using an arrayList, called `productList`

```
final String product_key=productList.get(position).getKey();
```

more info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getRef()

Answer (score 1):

Inside `onBindViewHolder` method you can get the key using the following line of code:

```
String product_key = getItem(position);
```

[getRef()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) is used to obtain a reference to the source location for the snapshot. So you can only use this method on a snapshot object. It returns a `DatabaseReference` and takes no argument. Below an example:

```
DatabaseReference ref = snapshot.child("users").getRef();
```